# How to set the timezone for mysql?

Tags: java, mysql, exception, timezone

I get this error:

> java.sql.SQLException: 
>       The server time zone value 'unknown' is unrecognized or represents more than one time zone. You must configure either the server or JDBC driver (via the serverTimezone configuration property) to use a more specific time zone value if you want to utilize time zone support.

I've tried changing the `convertToNull` to `CONVERT_TO_NULL` or `EXCEPTION` since I don't know what to do.

```
 String myURL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/registrationdata? 
 zeroDateTimeBehavior=CONVERT_TO_NULL";
```

I expect to save data to mysql but since I don't know how to set the timezeone, I always get an error.

Comment: have you tried setting  the timezone for example : `jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/registrationdata?serverTimezone=UTC` ?

Comment: it worked on my Registration_Form Class, but didn't worked on my Login_Form Class

Comment: From mysql client, what does the following return: SHOW global variables LIKE 'time_zone'